# Cannot find component with expression?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I used DataTable - Row Selection from prime faces to display list of users and when I run the page I faced this error

> Cannot find component with expression ":dialog1:employes" referenced from "dialog1:j_idt43:j_idt51"

```html
<h:form id="dialog1">
                <p:accordionPanel>
                    <p:tab title="nouveau Groupe">

                        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                            <h:outputLabel value="nom groupe" />
                            <p:inputText value="#{CalCulJobsBean.libelle}" />
                        </h:panelGrid>
                        <p:commandButton value="submit"
                            action="#{CalCulJobsBean.ajouter()}" icon="ui-icon-check"
                            style="margin-left: 40%"
                            oncomplete="PF('DialogAddGroupesalriers').hide()" />
                    </p:tab>

                    <p:tab title="liste Salariers">

                                    <h:outputLabel value="Matricule:" />
                                    <p:inputText value="#{donneesIndividuellesBean.matricule}"
                                        onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) {onchange(); return false; }">
                                        <p:ajax event="change"
                                            listener="#{donneesIndividuellesBean.chercherEmployesByMatricule()}"
                                            update=":dialog1:employes" /> 
                                    </p:inputText>
                                <!--    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-plus fa fa-plus"
                                        onclick="PF('dialog1').show()" update=":formdialog1">
                                    </p:commandButton> -->

                        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-plus fa fa-plus"
                            onclick="PF('dialog2').show()" update=":formdialog1">
                        </p:commandButton>



                            <p:panel header="liste des salariers">

                                <h2>select + to add</h2>
                                <p:dataTable id="employes"
                                value="#{donneesIndividuellesBean.employesCherches}" var="emp"
                                selection="#{donneesIndividuellesBean.identiteSelectionne}"
                                rowKey="#{emp.numedoss}" selectionMode="single">
                                <f:facet name="header">

                                </f:facet>
                            <!--    <p:ajax event="rowSelect"
                                     execute="@this"
                                    update=":employe" /> -->


                                <p:column style="width:40px">
                                    <p:graphicImage value="#{donneesIndividuellesBean.photoE}" cache="false"
                                        id="dragImg" style="width:30px; height:40px;">
                                        <f:param name="empid" value="#{emp.numedoss}" />
                                        <p:draggable for="dragImg" revert="true" helper="clone" />
                                    </p:graphicImage>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column headerText="Matricule">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{emp.matricul}" />
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column headerText="Nom">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{emp.nom}" />
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column headerText="Prenom">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{emp.prenom}" />
                                </p:column>


                            </p:dataTable>


                </p:accordionPanel>

            </h:form>
        </p:dialog>
```

What is the problem with my code ?

Answer (score 3):

In generally, JSF will generate component id whenever developers do not specific component id by automatically. Thus, you should specific id of the `<p:accordionPanel>` to skip generate by automatically.

In the case of, `<p:accordionPanel id="ac">` has an `id="ac"`, you can refer by `update=":dialog1:ac:employes"`

Comment: Though the solution to the problem is right your answer lacks explanatory power that I tried to compensate in my answer. Still, you get my upvote (as well for being active within the JSF-tagged questions).

Comment: @RayGR You are welcome, but you should mark green chech on the right solution.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the components within JSF/PrimeFaces implement the [`NamingContainer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/NamingContainer.html) inerface. Such components affect the way client ids of its children are generated. The examples of such components include [`<h:form>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/h/form.html) ([`HtmlForm`](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.2/javadocs/javax/faces/component/html/HtmlForm.html) class) and [`<p:accordionPanel>`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/5.1/core/primefaces-p/accordionPanel.html) ([`AccordionPanel`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/5.1/org/primefaces/component/accordionpanel/AccordionPanel.html) class). While you seem to be aware of the former, you did not know that the latter was a naming container as well.

When you want to AJAX-update a given component you need to specify either its id, in case it's located *relative to the same naming container*, or its client id, in case it's *relative to the view root*. Tying it to your view structure we get update=":formId:accordionPanelId:dataTableId".

The last issue to concern is that every component *must have an id set* so that it could be found within a component tree and surely be unique. In case you supply an id of your own, like in `id="myComponentId"`, *you will set the id* for the component. Otherwise component *id will be autogenerated* by the JSF framework for you: that's why you ind those `j_idt43` ids.

To sum it up, you need to explicitly specify id for your accordion panel and include it in your path to the to-be-updated component (exactly as proposed in [wittakarn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26900056/1820286)).